# Preserve hyperlink when pasting from sheets to docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am creating a Google Doc from a Google Sheet with a script. One cell is a hyperlink formula.

`=HYPERLINK('-automatization-!P2,'-automatization-!P3)`

That does not contain the link directly but includes a reference to it.

When copying it with the following code, the Google Doc either contains only the label (with `getValue()`) or the hyperlink formula that you can see above (with `getFormula()`)

```
function createdoc() {
  documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId()
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('XXXX ' + date);
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
  for (var i = 2; i<sheet.getLastRow();i++){
  companyname = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()
  description = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue()
  crunchbase = sheet.getRange(i,3).getFormula()
  body.appendParagraph(companyname);
  body.appendParagraph(description);
  body.appendParagraph(crunchbase);
}}
```

Does anybody have a solution to preserve the hyperlink when copying and pasting from Sheets to Docs?

Comment: Can you post a before/after image of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

how about `const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();const sh=ss.getSheetByName('-automatization-');const url=sh.getRange('P2').getValue();` Note: I hardly ever use formulas so you may have to correct this.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I was thinking about this as well. But then I would have to extract the location of the link from the text of the formula beforehand. I was hoping there was an easier solution. But thank you anyway!

Comment: You could use some string methods to do it programmatically.  Play around with it in the console of your developer tools until you get a method that works reliably